# Обрезать число до сотых без округления

Tags: php

Каким образом обрезать число до сотых, **не округляя** его?

```
echo number_format(0.65999, 2, '.', ''); // 0.66, Округлило
echo "\n";
echo intval(0.65999 * 100) / 100; // 0.65, Не округлило
echo "\n";
echo intval(0.29 * 100) / 100; // 0.28, Округлило
```

Перепробовал многие варианты из интернета, везде округление было ни на одном числе, так на другом. Есть какое-то нормальное решение или без собственной функции не обойтись?

https://ideone.com/qm7YUE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [`BCMath`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) и ее функцию `bcdiv`:

```
echo bcdiv(0.65999, 1, 2); // 0.65
```

Ну, и как вариант, можно использовать `preg_replace`:

```
echo preg_replace('/\.\d{2}\K.+/', '', 0.65999); // 0.65
```

Comment: bcdiv отличная функция, спасибо большое! Всё прекрасно работает!

Answer (score 2):

Есть функции ceil и floor:
`printf('%05.2f', floor(0.65999*100)/100);`

отсекаем дробную часть после умножения на сто и делим

Comment: Ваш вариант не округляет 0.65999, но округляет 0.29